# Pyspark: Output to csv -- Timestamp format is different

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with a dataset with the following Timestamp format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

When I output the data to csv the format changes to something like this: `2019-04-29T00:15:00.000Z`

Is there any way to get it to the original format like: `2019-04-29 00:15:00`

Do I need to convert that column to string and then push it to csv?

I am saying my file to csv like so:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv"
                                       ).mode('overwrite'
                                             ).option("header", "true"
                                               ).save("date_fix.csv")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Alternative

### spark >=2.0.0

set **option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")** for format("csv")

```scala
df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv"
                            ).mode('overwrite'
                            ).option("header", "true"
                            ).option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                            ).save("date_fix.csv")
```

As per documentation-

> `timestampFormat` (default `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`): sets the string that indicates a timestamp format. Custom date formats follow the formats at `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. This applies to timestamp type.

### spark < 2.0.0

set **option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")** for format("csv")

```scala
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv"
                            ).mode('overwrite'
                            ).option("header", "true"
                            ).option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                            ).save("date_fix.csv")
```

As per documentation-

> `dateFormat`: specifies a string that indicates the date format to use when reading dates or timestamps. Custom date formats follow the formats at java.text.SimpleDateFormat. This applies to both DateType and TimestampType. By default, it is null which means trying to parse times and date by java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf() and java.sql.Date.valueOf()

ref - [readme](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

Comment: I didn't know this, this is awesome! Every day is a school day. Have an upvote! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. The easiest way to achieve this is using `pyspark.sql.functions.date_format` such as:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn(
  "date_column_formatted",  
  f.date_format(f.col("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
)
```

More info about it here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: So my column is already correctly formatted in Timestamp in pyspark. My issue is that when I land my file to csv, it takes tacks on the `T` and `.000Z`. That's what I need to get rid of when saving my file to csv.

Comment: I understand - the problem is going to remain however, because your column is likely `TimestampType`, which will always get converted to the `ISO 8601` format. Maybe try just casting, rather than converting using `date_format`?

Comment: Ok makes sense, so cast my timestamp column to string and that should work?